# Substituir todos os caracteres de uma string por outro caracter

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    secretWord_copy = ""
    for i in secretWord:
        print(i)
        secretWord_copy = secretWord.replace(i," _ ")
    print(secretWord_copy)
secretWord = 'apple'
```

Estou tentando substituir cada caracter de `secretWord` por " - "  mas o código acima só substitui o último:

appl _

O que está errado?

O resultado deveria ser _ _ _ _ _

Comment: O resultado final deve ser "_____"?

Comment: @Barbetta:  O resultado deveria ser _ _ _ _ _

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está sempre substituindo secretWord sem modificá-la.

```
def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    secretWord_copy = ""
    for i in secretWord:
        print(i)
        secretWord_copy = secretWord.replace(i," _ ")
        secretWord = secretWord_copy
    print(secretWord_copy)
secretWord = 'apple'
```

Sem alterar `secretWord`:

```
def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    secretWord_copy = secretWord
    for i in secretWord:
        print(i)
        secretWord_copy = secretWord_copy.replace(i,"_")
    print(secretWord_copy)
    print(secretWord)
secretWord = 'apple'
```

Comment: Na verdade eu não queria alterar a secretWord, mas apenas a cópia. Preciso de mais uma variável?

Comment: @EdS veja a edição; é só atribuir o valor original à copia no começo.

Answer (score 4):

Me desculpem a pergunta, mas pra que serviria o segundo parametro (lettersGuessed) da função getGuessedWord. Porque pelo o que eu estou vendo ela não esta sendo usada. E pelo o que eu entendi da função, basta fazer o seguinte para obter o mesmo resultado:

```
    def getGuessedWord(secretWord):
        print (len (secretWord) * ' _ ')
```

Comment: A pergunta feita é em relação ao post, claro que o melhor seria usar comentários para tirar dúvidas da pergunta, mas a resposta é válida e a pergunta feita eu interpretei como uma ajuda ao autor em relação a criação de funções